# Exception Thrown/Exception Unhandled in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: exception, assembly, x86, stack, masm

At the instruction that says `ret 20` I get this error:

> Exception thrown at 0x007B1D3C in HWProject4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000068.

I assume it is because I am incorrectly accessing my stack but I do not know how. I drew the stack on paper and do not know what I am doing incorrectly.

The guidelines for the project are:
[image]

My Code:

```
include Irvine32.inc
ExitProcess Proto, dwexitcode: DWORD

.data
    num1    DWORD   1h
    num2    DWORD   2h
    num3    DWORD   3h
    num4    DWORD   4h
    num5    DWORD   5h
    numofVar    BYTE    5

    title1  BYTE    "System Parameters on Stack",0
    titledivider    BYTE    "---------------------------",0
    addresstxt  BYTE    "Address: ",0
    arrow   BYTE    " => ",0
    contenttxt  BYTE    "Content: ",0

.code

mdisplayText MACRO text, newLine:=<0>
    mov edx, OFFSET text
    call WriteString

    COMMENT !
    cmp newline, 0
    jz done
    mov ecx, newLine
L1:
    call crlf
    loop L1
    !

    IF (newLine GT 0)
        mov ecx, newLine
    L1:
        call crlf
        loop L1
    ELSE
        
    ENDIF


;done:
    ;ret

ENDM

runLevelTwo PROC ;,
    ;numbofVars:BYTE
    
    push ebp 
    mov ebp, esp
    pushad

    mov esi, ebp
    add esi, 8
    mov eax, 0
    mov eax, esi
    ;movzx ecx, numbofVars
    mov ecx, 5

displaying:
    mdisplayText addresstxt
    call WriteHex
    mdisplayText 'h'

    mdisplayText arrow

    mdisplayText contenttxt
    mov eax, [esi]
    call WriteHex
    mdisplayText 'h'
    call crlf

    add esi, type DWORD
    mov eax, esi
    loop displaying

    popad
    pop ebp

    ret 
runLevelTwo ENDP
    

runLevelOne PROC
    push num5
    push num4
    push num3
    push num2
    push num1
    
    call runLevelTwo ;numofVar
    ret 20

runLevelOne ENDP

main PROC
    mdisplayText title1, 1

    mov edx, OFFSET titledivider
    call WriteString
    call crlf

    call runLevelOne
    

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: `ret 20` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @RaymondChen I thought it clears 20 bytes of stack?

Comment: Yes, *after* popping a return address.  It's for callee-pops conventions, removing extra stuff above your return address, not below.  ESP needs to point to your return address when you execute `ret`, regardless of `ret 20` vs. `ret 0`.  Use a debugger: you'll see EIP ends up at the address of one of the args you pushed (or somewhere else if `runLevelTwo` modifies its incoming stack args before returning).  And since you've identified the problem instruction, read the manual for it carefully: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret although to be fair it's pseudocode is cluttered with variants.

Comment: @PeterCordes would you be able to show me the change in my code to make this possible? I’m more of a visual learner, sorry.

Comment: `ret 20` should be replaced with something like `add esp, 20` `ret`. `Ret 20` pops off the return address from the stack and then adds 20 to esp where you want to remove 20 bytes from the stack which results in the return address on the top of the stack and then `ret` would return out of the function.

Comment: @MichaelPetch okay I will try that when I get home and let you know how it goes, thank you. Does the rest of my code look sufficient to execute what this project asks?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Im still getting the exception message but this time, i have it on add esp, 20. Is there anything else i can do?

Comment: `add esp, 20` doesn't access memory, there's no way it can cause that exception.  Make sure you rebuild your executable from source before re-running.  Michael Petch is correct, `add esp, 20` / `ret` is the right fix for that bug.  You might have other bugs, but you have a debugger to single-step and see what's going on so you're in the best position to look for them, not people just looking at the source.

Comment: Don't forget to cite the outside assistance you received on your assignment.

Comment: If you run your program in the debugger and just let it go until the error the exception handling likely stops you at the line of code in the debugger after `call runLevelTwo` which is either your original `ret 20` or `add esp, 20`. This is not the offending line. You should step through the code line by line. You'd notice that things go well until the point you do  `mdisplayText 'h'`. Your `mdisplayText` macro assumes what is passed is an address to text, not an actual character!

Comment: You could put the `h` character in a string called `hexsuffix` in the `.data` section with something like `hexsuffix BYTE "h", 0`. Then replace both occurrences of `mdisplayText 'h'` with `mdisplayText hexsuffix`

Comment: @MichaelPetch you, my friend, are a walking legend. That one small change to hexsuffix literally just made my entire code work.